# How to save changed SimpleXML object back to file?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

So, I have this code that searches for a particular node in my XML file, unsets an existing node and inserts a brand new child node with the correct data.  Is there a way of getting this new data to save within the actual XML file with simpleXML?  If not, is there another efficient method for doing this?

```
public function hint_insert() {

    foreach($this->hints as $key => $value) {

        $filename = $this->get_qid_filename($key);

        echo "$key - $filename - $value[0]<br>";

        //insert hint within right node using simplexml
        $xml = simplexml_load_file($filename);

        foreach ($xml->PrintQuestion as $PrintQuestion) {

            unset($xml->PrintQuestion->content->multichoice->feedback->hint->Passage);

            $xml->PrintQuestion->content->multichoice->feedback->hint->addChild('Passage', $value[0]);

            echo("<pre>" . print_r($PrintQuestion) . "</pre>");
            return;

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Not sure I understand the issue. The [`asXML()`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.asxml.php) method accepts an optional filename as param that will save the current structure as XML to a file. So once you have updated your XML with the hints, just save it back to file.

```
// Load XML with SimpleXml from string
$root = simplexml_load_string('<root><a>foo</a></root>');
// Modify a node
$root->a = 'bar';
// Saving the whole modified XML to a new filename
$root->asXml('updated.xml');
// Save only the modified node
$root->a->asXml('only-a.xml');
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to save the same, you can use [`dom_import_simplexml`](http://www.php.net/function.dom_import_simplexml) to convert to a DomElement and save:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->formatOutput = true;
$dom->loadXML($simpleXml->asXML());
echo $dom->saveXML();
```

Comment: So looking at my code above, this will save my updated $xml object to whatever $filename is?

Comment: I tried changing it to             $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
   $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
   $dom->formatOutput = true;
   $dom->loadXML($xml->asXML());
   $dom->save($filename);

But still no update in the file

Comment: Ok, actually it does work now with the $dom->save($filename)...

Thanks!

Comment: @Sarfraz Your example does not use `dom_import_simplexml`. You are loading the XML string from `asXML()`, which is the function to output or **save a file** with SimpleXml, so why DOM? The only advantage of using DOM is you can format the output, which is only needed when people are authoring it by hand.

Comment: @Gordon: I forgot to add that line but later after seeing the OP's comment he said it worked, then i didn't write anymore otherwise yes it was needed and that is now there with your comment for OP if he wishes.