# PHP: How do I write XML object into a XML file

Tags: php, xml, object

There is a XML file with following content :

```
<StaticDataRequest>
   <Header>
      <Code>XXXX</Code>
      <Username>XXXX</Username>
      <Password>XXXX</Password>
   </Header>
   <Body>
      <GetStaticData>countries</GetStaticData>
   </Body>
</StaticDataRequest>
```

I need to change `Code, Username, Password` values of the above file and save it.

So, I read that file by following command :

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("country_request.xml");
```

And I changed elements values as below:

```
$xml->Header->Code = 'myCode';
$xml->Header->Username  = 'myUsername';
$xml->Header->Password  = 'myPassword';
```

Now, `$xml` is an object with following structure:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [Header] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [Code] => myCode
            [Username] => myUsername
            [Password] => myPassword
        )

    [Body] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [GetStaticData] => countries
        )
)
```

**The Question**

The main question is how can I write `$xml` into a XML file with XML structure?

That would be like this:

```
<StaticDataRequest>
       <Header>
          <Code>myCode</Code>
          <Username>myUsername</Username>
          <Password>myPassword</Password>
       </Header>
       <Body>
          <GetStaticData>countries</GetStaticData>
       </Body>
</StaticDataRequest>
```

Comment: Could you include in the title the programming language you are using?

Comment: A similar question was asked and deleted by you yesterday.

Comment: You can use [SimpleXMLElement::asXML](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.asxml.php) with an filename as argument, to write the XML-doc to that filename. Like `$xml->asXML('myfile.xml');`.

Comment: @AmitThakur Yes. But more details added now...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to save changed SimpleXML object back to file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418376/how-to-save-changed-simplexml-object-back-to-file)

Comment: @vstm and skroczek. Thank you. solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`simplexml_load_file` returns a [`SimpleXMLElement`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) object. If you look through the documentation you will find this:

> public mixed asXML ([ string $filename ] )

In other words:

```
$file = "country_request.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($file);

// Do you stuff here...

if ($xml->asXML($file)) {
    echo 'Saved!';
} else {
    echo 'Unable to save to file :(';
}
```

Comment: It worked tnx, But  first line of `$file` contains its xml version `<?xml version="1.0"?>`. can I write into `$file` without XML version at the first line?

Comment: @user41888 XML files should have a version. But if you really want it gone then [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947695/remove-xml-version-tag-when-a-xml-is-created-in-php) should help you out.